# Symfony2 - Serialize object with relations (ManyToMany, OneToMany ...)

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization, entity

Can someone tell me if it's possible to serialize an entity that have relations ?
json_encode already works but my object looks like this :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "lot": 32,
  "num": "533987",
  "date_modification": {
      "date": "2015-02-17 14:24:52",
      "timezone_type": 3,
      "timezone": "Europe/Paris"
  },
  "customer": {
      "id": 1,
      "lastname": "DUFRESNE",
      "firstname": "CHRISTOPHE",
  }
}
```

But i would like to serialize data withotu sub objects. in fact like this :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "lot": 32,
  "num": "533987",
  "date_modification": "2015-02-17",
  "customer": "DUFRESNE CHRISTOPHE",
  }
}
```

So i checked the doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html
But i can't see if it's possible to works with relations like ManyToMany, etc and how to do it ?

Here is my Entity :

```
/**
 * Subscription (BS)
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="subscription")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Jcd\LiteyearBundle\Entity\SubscriptionRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */

class Subscription {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lot", type="smallint")
     */
    private $lot;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="num", type="string", length=9)
     */
    private $num;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_creation", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date_creation;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_modification", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date_modification;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_completeness", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date_completeness;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_reception", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date_reception;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_signature", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date_signature;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_entry", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date_entry;

    /**
     * @var \Integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="statement", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $statement; // Releve du compteur

    /**
     * @var \Integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="statement_kind", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $statement_kind; // Personne qui a relevé le compteur

    /**
     * @var \Integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="car", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $car; // Consommation annuelle de reference

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro", type="boolean", options={"default" = false}, nullable=true)
     */
    private $pro;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Jcd\LiteyearBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="adv_subscriptions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="adv_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $adv;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Jcd\LiteyearBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="vendor_subscriptions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="vendor_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $vendor;

    /**
     * @var \Integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="provider", type="integer")
     */
    private $provider;

    /**
     * @var \Integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="integer")
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @var \Integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="payment", type="integer")
     */
    private $payment;

    /**
     * @var \Integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="billing", type="integer")
     */
    private $billing;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $comment;

    /**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(name="wage", type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $wage; // Anciennement Rem

    /**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(name="com", type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $com; // Anciennement Commission

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="offer", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $offer; // Anciennement Prix fixe

    /**
     * @var \Integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="mail_kind", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $mail_kind; //Anciennement Mail

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SubscriptionTrack", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, mappedBy="subscription")
     */
    private $tracks;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SubscriptionSalary", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="subscriptions")
     **/
    private $salaries;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Jcd\LiteyearBundle\Entity\Customer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $customer;
```

Thank you for you answer !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use `JMSSerializerBundle` that has many features that you might want to use.

Give it a try: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Answer is "Use `JMSSerializerBundle`". Link is just for not googling it.

Comment: And if `JMSSerializerBundle` is ever changed in a way that would remove the functionality sought by the OP or the link changes, your answer is still invalidated.

Comment: And in this case someone will answer this question with new right answer. If I delete link and write explanations how to install this bundle it will also be invalidated in this case;-)
Again, this IS NOT link-only answer. This link is just for convenient moving to the place where library lives. It can be googled. There are many other links that will teach you how to install it via composer. There is no need to post all these links.